# Metrics to consider for heavily imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, metrics

I am trying to train a `GradientBoosting` model on a heavily imbalanced data in `Python`. Class distribution is like `0.96 : 0.04` for class 0 and class 1 respectively.

After some parameter tuning considering the `recall` and `precision` scores I came up with a good model. Different metrics scores are like given below for validation set. Also, it is close to the Cross Validation Scores.

`recall : 0.928777`
`precision : 0.974747`
`auc : 0.9636`
`kappa : 0.948455`
`f1 weighted : 0.994728`

If I want to tune the model further, which metrics should I consider to increase.? In my problem miss-classifying 1 as 0 is more problematic than miss-predicting 0 as 1.

Comment: Please let me know the Reason for down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various techniques to work with when dealing with Class imbalance issue. Few as stated below:

(Links include pythons `imblearn` [package](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/index.html) and `costcla` [package](https://pypi.org/project/costcla/))

1. Resample:

   - [Undersample](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.under_sampling) majority class (class 0 in your case) You can try [random undersampling](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/auto_examples/under-sampling/plot_random_under_sampler.html) for starters.
   - [Oversample](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.over_sampling) the minority class (Class 1). Explore SMOTE/ADASYN techniques.
2. Ensemble Techniques:

   - [Bagging/Boosting](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/api.html#module-imblearn.ensemble) techniques.
3. [Cost-sensitive Learning](https://pypi.org/project/costcla/): You should definitely explore this since you have mentioned:

> In my problem miss-classifying 1 as 0 is more problematic than miss-predicting 0 as 1.

In cost sensitive learning using `costcla` package, you should try the [following](http://albahnsen.github.io/CostSensitiveClassification/Sampling.html) approach, keeping your base classifier as GradientBoostingRegressor:

```
costcla.sampling.cost_sampling(X, y, cost_mat, method='RejectionSampling', oversampling_norm=0.1, max_wc=97.5)
```

Here you can load a cost_mat[C_FP,C_FN,C_TP,C_TN] for each data point in train and test. C_FP and C_FN are based on the misclassification cost that you want to set for positives and negatives classes. Refer to the full tutorial on credit score data [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/albahnsen/CostSensitiveClassification/blob/master/doc/tutorials/tutorial_edcs_credit_scoring.ipynb).

Comment: How is the cost matrix calculated.? Should I manually compute it myself.?

Comment: Ideally, you can put the cost as the inverse of proportion weights: 0.96: 0.04. cost of misclassifying 0 is much less than 1. Later you can fine tune as per your model results.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)